# Do While loop always exits after first loop

Tags: c, loops, scanf

I'm trying to make a small address book program in C where users would enter contact info which is stored in a text file. If a user opts to add a new contact, the program should ask them if they want to add another when they're finished. I've made an if statement which I believe should end the loop if they enter 'n' or continue for another contact if they write anything else. However if the user types 'y' (or anything else) it always exits after only 1 loop.

```
void new_contact(void){
    printf("Ready for new contact\n");
    int enter_new_contact = 1;
    char first_name[15];
    char second_name[20];
    char phone_number[12];
    char email[50];
    char y_n[1];
    do{
        printf("Enter the contacts first name.\n");
        scanf("%s", first_name);

        printf("Enter the contacts second name.\n");
        scanf("%s", second_name);

        printf("Enter the contacts phone number.\n");
        scanf("%s", phone_number);

        printf("Enter the contacts email.\n");
        scanf("%s", email);

        printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n", first_name, second_name, phone_number, email);

        printf("Would you like to add another contact?\n");
        scanf("%s", y_n);
        printf("%s\n", y_n);

        if(strcmp(y_n, "n")==0){
            enter_new_contact=0;
        }

    }while(enter_new_contact==1);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First thing: fix undefined behavior such as `char y_n[1];` being not large enough to hold a character and a null terminator.

Comment: `char y_n[1];`: This char buffer is way too small. It cannot hold any sensible string. You need room for the null terminator. And what happens when the user enters "yes" or "no"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
scanf("%s", y_n);
```

You have undefined behaviour here when scanf() tries to put `'\0'` in `y_n`, to which you allotted only one character. You should instead declare it as

```
char y_n[2];
```

and change the scanf statement to

```
scanf("%1s", y_n);
```

Comment: Why not just `char y_n` instead?

Comment: @CinCout: Scanning chars has the problem that every char is considered. There are heaps of questions where the newline is read instead of the intended character. The method above that restricts reading to one character has problems, too: When the user enters "yes", which is a reasonable answer to the question, only the "y" will be scanned and the next contact's first name will be "es". `scanf` isn't really suited to interactive input, in my opinion.